# how to drop X-Frame-Options response headers,, allowing app to be iframed

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, iframe, meteor

my original issue is...
i'm getting facebook dialog error: `An error ocurred. Please try again later.`

the only thing solving this issue is by installing chrome extension...

Ignore X-Frame headers (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe)

so i suspect this is due to browser content policy..

**tested on:** chrome and safari

**os:** mac osx 10.10

**server:** localhost/nodejs

i try to solve this issue by installing `browser-policy` package and then setup...

**server/policy.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  BrowserPolicy.framing.allowAll();
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowInlineScripts();
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowEval();
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowInlineStyles();
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowDataUrlForAll();
  BrowserPolicy.content.allowSameOriginForAll();
});

BrowserPolicy.framing.allowAll();
BrowserPolicy.content.allowInlineScripts();
BrowserPolicy.content.allowEval();
BrowserPolicy.content.allowInlineStyles();
BrowserPolicy.content.allowDataUrlForAll();
BrowserPolicy.content.allowSameOriginForAll();
```

however i just come up with another issue: all external resources (font, javascript facebook sdk, etc) couldn't be loaded due to violating content security policy..

**summary**

i just need to drop X-Frame-Options response headers,, allowing to be iframed by facebook,, either to use browser policy or not... and of course without forcing users to install any extension...

any help would be appreciated... thank Youu,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the response header of the requests coming to your server to the following value

"X-Frame-Options", "ALLOW-FROM SAMEDOMAIN, www.facebook.com/MyFBSite"

you can do that globally by setting this header via filter